# Using function from another file for calculation

Tags: python, function, mean

I am trying to use a function from another file for calculation. I have a script where I want to calculate the mean by using a function from another file where I already received the amount of words a specific text has. This number I want to use in my current script for calculating the mean. The function I'm trying to use looks as follows:

```
def Word(liste):
    test =(len(liste))
```

My try to add this for calculating the mean looks like this:

```
def mean(liste, Word):
        
    Sum = (sum(liste))
    result = Sum/Word
    print(result)
```

Unfortunately I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'function'
```

But how can I change the function to an integer? Is that even possible?

Comment: list is a python buildin, dont use it as a varibale name

Comment: oh sorry yeah I already changed that to the german word for list so liste, but it still doesn't work the way I want it to

Comment: Please include the line where you call `mean`. It looks like you are passing `Word` to it, which is a function. And you can't divide float with a function (as error states). Although `Word` doesn't really return anything (it returns `None` implicitly), so dividing float by `None` would also fail.

Comment: Why is `Word` a parameter in `mean`? Can you remove the parameter and just use the imported `Word`?

Comment: Also, like @YevhenKuzmovych said, `Word` does nothing but call `len` and return `None`. Maybe you can just use `len` instead of writing your own function.

Answer (score 1):

To the word function add return statement as follows

```
def Word(liste):
    test =(len(liste))
    return test
```

And to mean function modify

```
result = Sum/Word(liste)
```